# loading 2D arrays into a java linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I am a new programmer writing a sudoku program.  I have guess values stored into a linked list structure.  I have a method which determines where the best guess location is and then guesses all possible values for that entry.

My specific question is that when I loop thru to enter multiple guesses, the subsequent guesses overwrite the earlier guesses so I end up with guessQueue holding multiple copies of the same guess.  How should I call the loading into the linked list to avoid this problem?  I created a short sample method which illustrates the point here (and hopefully is SCCE):

```
public void TestLinkedList(){
    LinkedList testQueue = new LinkedList();
    int[][] testGrid = new int[9][9];
    for (int k=0;k<10;k++){
        for (int j=0;j<9;j++){
            for (int jj=0;jj<9;jj++){
                testGrid[j][jj]=k;
            }            
        }
        testQueue.addLast(testGrid);
    }
}
```

I expect each entry in the linked list to contain an array with each value in the array 1 higher than the previous entry into the linked list, but all the values in the arrays in the linked list are the same

Comment: You have a three-dimensional array which isn't explained or declared anywhere.

Comment: isPlausible is a a 9x9x9 boolean. It is indexed from zero row, column, digit.  It is true if that cell in the grid could plausibly that digit and false if it cannot plausibly be that cell or if the cell value is known in the current grid.  I added class definitions to the original post

Comment: This isn't a "here's all my code, please fix it" site. Post an [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org)

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post.  I totally revised the posted code to distill down what I am asking

Answer (score 1):

The Arrays class and the Collections framework can help you out:

Java Code:
T[] array= new T[ ... ];
List list= new LinkedList(Arrays.asList(array));

Comment: I want a list of arrays, not an array as a list.  I want a 9x9xn data set with n arbitrary in size with fast insertion and retrieval of the first 9x9 block of data